# How to exchange data between MySQL and Parse.com?

Tags: mysql, parse-platform, exchange-server

We plan to use a MySQL database as the backend for our (Java or Ruby on Rails) based web application. After completing the web application, we want to port the application to iOS and Android.

We want to be able to run the application in "native" mode - that is, if a network connection is not available to the smart-phone, the system should be able to store the data locally, and sync with the backend when the network connection becomes available.

The best kind of framework for this kind of syncing is a library/framework such as Parse.com.

The question to which we want an answer is: is it possible to exchange data between the web application data stored in MySQL, and the Parse.com data which is stored in a proprietary format on the Parse servers?

Comment: Another application that uses the same idea is to have a raspberry pi storing sensor data into a local mysql or sqlite DB and then sync back to parse.com. The data collection will work even without internet connection, and data will be available online as soon as internet connection is available.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question: It is indeed possible, but syncing data is an advanced topic.

However, you also state that you want to access the parse data when offline. As I understand it, you want Parse to handle the offline state, and then sync to MySQL when connection is back up. Parse does not offer functionality to store data offline, other than caching requests. You probably need another service for your specific needs.

I might have misunderstood the use case. If so, my alternate understanding would be that ALL data for the smart phones will be handled by parse: both offline and online, with syncing. The answer is still: parse does not offer this kind of functionality.